# Python - Create constant array of unique elements

Tags: python, arrays

I recently tried to instantiate a 4x4 constant (0's) array by using

```
a = [[0] * 4] * 4
```

which instantiates the array `a` as

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However, this does not create an array of unique elements as altering an element in any of the arrays changes all of them, e.g.:

```
a[0][0] = 1
```

alters `a` to

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I think I understand why this happens (copies of lists copy the list's pointer and do not create separate copies unless specified, unlike int's, etc.) but am left wondering:

**Is there any quick and easy way to instantiate a constant array (without using any external modules, such as NumPy) with unique elements that can later be altered by simple `a[i][j] = x` addressing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [[0 for _ in xrange(4)] for _ in xrange(4)]
```

should do it, it'll create separate lists

Answer (score 2):

Just for free. What is going on here ? When one does

```
>>> a = [[0] * 4] * 4
```

first,  one creates one list `[0] * 4` with four `0` elements. Let call this list `li`.

Then when you do `[li] * 4`, one actually creates a list which refers four times to the same object. See

```
>>> [id(el) for el in a]
[8696976, 8696976, 8696976, 8696976] # in my case
```

Whence the (not that) curious result one gets when entry-wise assigning like so

```
>>> a[0][0] = 1
[[1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

A solution is simply to ensure that each element of the list really is unique. For example doing

```
#Python2
>>> a = map(lambda _: [0]*4, range(4))
#Python3
>>> a = list(map(lambda _: [0]*4, range(4)))
#Python2&3
>>> a[0][0] = 1
[[1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```